# C Language: I want to add all the positive integers when a negative number is inserted

Tags: c

I want to add all the positive integers when a negative number is entered.

[Click for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iewmD.png)

```
int number;
int total;
int loopcount;
int a;
number = 0;
a = 0;
total = 0;

for(loopcount = 0; loopcount >=0; loopcount = loopcount + 1)
{
    printf("Enter Integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    a = number;

    if (a >= 0)
    {
        total = total + number;
    }
    else if(a < 0)
    {
        printf("Total positive int = %d\n", &total);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  It isn't visible.  What's the problem?  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  The code you've shown is close to an MCVE ([MCVE]); people probably can add `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main(void){` at the top and `return 0; }` at the bottom, but those few lines wouldn't hurt.

Comment: It is not clear why you are using both `number` and `a`.  Either one on its own would suffice if used consistently.

Comment: Alternatively, a simple `while (1) {...}` loop would have looked nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
printf("Total positive int = %d\n", &total);
                                    ^
```

Instead of printing value of `total` variable, you are printing the address of it. Remove `&`.
Correct way is:

```
printf("Total positive int = %d\n", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor bug in your code here:

```
printf("Total positive int = %d\n", &total);
                                    ^
```

When this is changed to:

```
printf("Total positive int = %d\n", total);
```

A simpler version of the same would look like:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number = 0;
    int total = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter Integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &number);

        if (number >= 0)
        {
            total += number;
        }
        else if(number < 0)
        {
            total += number;
            printf("Total positive int = %d\n", total);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code will do what it says, but it will also do different things if valid input is not inserted. Because, it doesn't take care of inputs that are not numbers.

Here is the one, that takes care of validating inputs and only allows numbers.

This version below has a lot to improve on, but I prefer it this way for letting learners understand the code and improve it further.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) 
{ 
    char str[10] = { 0 }; //Assuming that the number can only be restricted to 9 digits. Change as required!
    char *ptr = NULL;
    double ret = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;

    printf("Enter numbers: ");

    while(1)
    {
        str[0] = '\0';

        scanf("%s", str);
        ret = strtod(str, &ptr);
        if(ret == 0.0)
        {
           if(ptr != NULL)
           {
               printf("\nNot a number!");
               continue;
           }
           else
           {
               total += ret;
           }
        }
        else if(ret < 0.0)
        {
           total += ret;
           break;
        }
        else
        {
           total += ret;
        }
    }

    printf("\n%lf", total);

    return(0);
}
```